# i have a Nvarchar Column in a table in SQl Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, select, split, int, varchar

**column** is a **nvarchar** (15)

that above column consists of digits and characters for example

**column** consists data like row 1: **60 Units** row2: **2 Units** row3: **100 Units** row 4 :**1000 Units**

i want to only numeric values into separate column? how can i do that i tried but i don't get it i show you my query

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, column) as abc from table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data actually contains `units`, then you could use [`replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
select 
  cast(replace(col, ' units', '') as int) col
from yt
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/645f77/1)

You could also use [`substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and [`charindex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to return everything before the word:

```
select cast(substring(col, 1, charindex(' ', col)) as int) col
from yt
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/645f77/7).

If you might have number values without the `units`, then you can use:

```
select 
  case 
    when charindex(' ', col) > 0
    then cast(substring(col, 1, charindex(' ', col)) as int)
    else cast(col as int) end col
from yt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/665e2/4)

Comment: if there is no character then also numeric value should be come

Comment: there is any other query without end because when i write this one in trigger it gives an error

Comment: @Anjali This first one will work no matter what -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74e02d/1

Comment: we cannot find a numeric value in an alphanumeric string

Comment: that alphanumeric should be like 60abcd,abcd60,60units,60 units

Comment: @Anjali Since your requirements keep changing I would suggest to post a new question with all of the details about the data that is in the table and what you want as a desired result.

Comment: SELECT SUBSTRING(abcd, 1, COALESCE(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', abcd) - CASE WHEN LEN(abcd) - LEN(REPLACE(abcd, '.', '')) >= 2 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, -1), LEN(abcd)))
FROM    table